# AWS ECS-CLI docker-compose.yml depends_on error "services.nginx.depends_on.0 must be a string"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I was learning FARGATE services using AWS-ecs-cli.
I was trying to execute `ecs-cli compose --file docker-compose.yml service start`.
But the error message said,

`ERRO[0000] Unable to open ECS Compose Project error="services.nginx.depends_on.0 must be a string"   FATA[0000] Unable to create and read ECS Compose Project  error="services.nginx.depends_on.0 must be a string"`

How can I solve this problem? Here is my code about 'docker-compose.yml'

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    essential: true
    build: ./nginx
    image: [ECR Image URI]
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker-server
      - /var/log/nginx
    depends_on:
      - container_name: django
  django:
    essential: true
    build: ./fastcampus_test
    image: [ECR Image URI]
    restart: always
    command: uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker-server
      - /var/log/uwsgi
```

Comment: I also tried to change  [- container_name: django] to [- container_name: "django"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
depends_on:
  - django
```

In YAML, lines that start with `-` can be thought of as lists, and lines with a colon are key/value maps. In your case you want a list of strings (your error is describing offset 0 of your depends_on list).